# INNER JOIN nao esta aparecendo duas linhas na tabela

Tags: sql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no sql INNER JOIN
duas linhas da minha tabela não aparece.

```
SELECT Rma.cod_rma,Rma.cliente_rma,Produto.Sku_prod,Produto.Nome_prod,  Rma.Serial_rma
FROM Rma
INNER JOIN Produto
ON Produto.Sku_prod = Rma.Sku_prod
```

Comment: não entendi bulhufas do problema

Comment: estou tentando fazer uma consulta no sql

Comment: quando eu executo a tabela duas linhas nao aparece

Comment: na minha tabela tem 22 linhas e aparece só 20 quando eu executo a consulta

Comment: Pode ser que nem todos os registros que você está consultando tenham relacionamento, por esse motivo não aparecem todos os registros.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente estas linhas não possuem o mesmo valor. No Inner Join é mostrado somente quando há a mesma Key em ambas tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mesmo se eu executo so a tabela com select a tabela pula duas linhas

Comment: Pelo que aparenta, o erro estar aqui:
ON Produto.Sku_prod = Rma.Sku_prod

Talvez os registros estejam diferentes